# Rows to Columns with Row as Column Name Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a query which I need to transpose the rows returned into separate columns, but I need the column names returned from the row values, and another field as the value under these columns.

Ultimately this will be going into Excel. I initially thought I could do it with a pivot, but the values field cannot accept text without some work, and there are too many "film right types" to work with. I know the specific rights type currently, but the right descriptions and number of rights may change in the future, so I want it to be as flexible as possible.

I want to group by producer, film and country, with the "Film Right Type" as the columns going across, and the "Availability" as the value for the right type column.

My query as it stands.

```
Select product_detail.pd_product_code as 'ProductCode',
product_analysis.pa_m_9 as 'Producer',
product_detail.pd_abbv_description as 'Film',
product_detail.pd_commodity_code as 'Country',
variant_analysis.vaa_c_10 as 'Film Right Type',
case when isnull(variant_analysis.vaa_l_1,0) = 0 then  'Non-Exclusive' 
Else 
    case when dateadd(day,datediff(DAY,0,isnull(orders.LastDate,getdate())),0) > dateadd(day,datediff(DAY,0,getdate()),0) 
    Then 'Available On '+convert(varchar(10),Orders.LastDate, 103)
    Else 'Available' 
    End
end as 'Availability'

From product_detail
join variant_detail on variant_detail.vad_pd_id = product_detail.pd_id
left join variant_analysis on variant_analysis.vaa_vad_id = variant_Detail.vad_id
left join product_analysis on product_analysis.pa_pd_id = product_detail.pd_id
join (select count(variant_detail.vad_id) as CountVariants, variant_Detail.vad_pd_id from variant_Detail group by variant_detail.vad_pd_id) as Variants on Variants.vad_pd_id = product_detail.pd_id
Outer Apply
    (select top 1
    customer_detail.cd_statement_name as Customer,
    order_header_analysis.oha_d_2 as LastDate, 
    system_order_type.sot_description as OrderType, 
    order_header.oh_order_number as OrderNo
    from order_header
    join customer_detail on customer_detail.cd_id = order_header.oh_cd_id
    join order_line_item on order_line_item.oli_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
    join system_order_type on system_order_type.sot_id = order_header.oh_sot_id
    left join order_header_analysis on order_header_analysis.oha_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
    where order_header_analysis.oha_d_2 >= getdate()
    and order_header.oh_sot_id in (1, 2, 3)
    and order_line_item.oli_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
    ORder By order_header_analysis.oha_d_2 desc) as Orders 
where isnull(variant_analysis.vaa_l_2,0) = 0
```

This is the data I currently get out of it:
[image: current data]

This is how I want the end result.
[image]

---

**Edit:
I have nearly got this doing what I want after using a pivot.
My below query gives me exactly what I need:**

```
Select * 

From(   
Select product_detail.pd_product_code as 'ProductCode',
product_analysis.pa_m_9 as 'Producer',
product_detail.pd_abbv_description as 'Film',
product_detail.pd_commodity_code as 'Country',
variant_analysis.vaa_c_10 as 'FilmRightType',
case when isnull(variant_analysis.vaa_l_1,0) = 0 then  'Non-Exclusive' 
Else 
    case when dateadd(day,datediff(DAY,0,isnull(orders.LastDate,getdate())),0) > dateadd(day,datediff(DAY,0,getdate()),0) 
    Then 'Available On '+convert(varchar(10),Orders.LastDate, 103)
    Else 'Available' 
    End
end as 'Availability'

From product_detail
join variant_detail on variant_detail.vad_pd_id = product_detail.pd_id
left join variant_analysis on variant_analysis.vaa_vad_id = variant_Detail.vad_id
left join product_analysis on product_analysis.pa_pd_id = product_detail.pd_id
join (select count(variant_detail.vad_id) as CountVariants, variant_Detail.vad_pd_id from variant_Detail group by variant_detail.vad_pd_id) as Variants on Variants.vad_pd_id = product_detail.pd_id
Outer Apply
    (select top 1
    customer_detail.cd_statement_name as Customer,
    order_header_analysis.oha_d_2 as LastDate, 
    system_order_type.sot_description as OrderType, 
    order_header.oh_order_number as OrderNo
    from order_header
    join customer_detail on customer_detail.cd_id = order_header.oh_cd_id
    join order_line_item on order_line_item.oli_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
    join system_order_type on system_order_type.sot_id = order_header.oh_sot_id
    left join order_header_analysis on order_header_analysis.oha_oh_id = order_header.oh_id
    where order_header_analysis.oha_d_2 >= getdate()
    and order_header.oh_sot_id in (1, 2, 3)
    and order_line_item.oli_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
    ORder By order_header_analysis.oha_d_2 desc) as Orders 
where isnull(variant_analysis.vaa_l_2,0) = 0
) as FilmVals

pivot
(
  max(Availability)
  for FilmRightType in (
    [Theatrical], [DVD], [Blu ray], [Free TV], [Pay TV], [Video on Demand Catch Up], [Subscription Video on Demand], [Advertising Video on Demand], [TV On Demand Download to Own], [TV On Demand Download to Rent]
  )
) piv;
```

I want to set the list of RightTypes to be dynamic from the DB.
I've created another query using for XML Path and this returns the data in the correct format:

```
(Select left(RightType.RightTypesList,len(RightType.RightTypesList)-1) From (Select
    (Select
    DISTINCT
    '['+variant_analysis.vaa_c_10+']'+', '
    from variant_analysis
    where variant_analysis.vaa_c_10  is not null
    order by 1
    For XML Path ('')) as RightTypesList) as RightType)
```

But when I put this in place of the hard coded list, I get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 44
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use PIVOT operator in SQL
[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) is an example

Comment: I have nearly got this working how I want. I've edited my main question with the updated query and details.

Comment: I could not find a way to set the in ( of the pivot using a sub query. As this is in Excel, I could execute is as a separate query, then grab the value as text in VBA and dynamically insert in this query.

Comment: And what about dynamic query in sql ? You could prepare propper query as a string (of Course in slq) and then run It.